# Remove circles for zero values in a stem plot in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am plotting some discrete values with a stem plot in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB). I found that if the value is zero, the stem plot will put a circle on the x axis to show the zeros. Is there a way to have a stem NOT showing the circles if the value is zero?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Treat them as NaN's, ie:

```
Y = [1;2;3;0;3;2;4;0;1];
Y(Y == 0) = NaN;
stem(Y);
```

The 4th and 8th index will still exist on the x-axis, but if the observation is set to `NaN`, no line or circle will be plotted.